# migrateStoreFromURL method gives error

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, core-data

I am trying to migrate db like this -

```
    NSError                         *error = nil;
    NSMappingModel                  *mapping = [NSMappingModel inferredMappingModelForSourceModel: oldModel destinationModel: self error: &error];

    NSString                        *newContextPath = [contextPath stringByAppendingPathExtension: @"tmp"];
    NSValue                         *classValue = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator registeredStoreTypes] objectForKey: NSSQLiteStoreType];
    Class                           sqliteStoreClass = (Class)[classValue pointerValue];
    Class                           sqliteStoreMigrationManagerClass = [sqliteStoreClass migrationManagerClass];
    NSMigrationManager              *manager = [[sqliteStoreMigrationManagerClass alloc] initWithSourceModel: oldModel destinationModel: self];
    @try {
        if (![manager migrateStoreFromURL: srcURL type:NSSQLiteStoreType options:nil withMappingModel:mapping toDestinationURL: dstURL destinationType:NSSQLiteStoreType destinationOptions:nil error:&error]) {
            LOG(@"Migration failed %@", error);
            return NO;
        }
    } @catch (NSException *exception) {
        LOG(@"Exception: %@", exception);
        return NO;
    }

    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath: contextPath error: &error]) {
        return NO;
    }
    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] moveItemAtPath: newContextPath toPath: contextPath error: &error]) {
        return NO;
    }
```

I am getting this error when I try to write the current model to db, **BUG IN CLIENT OF libsqlite3.dylib: database integrity compromised by API violation: vnode unlinked while in use:**
though it is migrated successfully. When I try to access the migrated db, it says its corrupted or malformed and crashes. Not sure what I am doing wrong. It was all working fine and still working fine in iOS 10. Happens only in iOS11.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Did you receive any solution?

Comment: No, I couldn’t.. I was just able to fix the crash..